# Division of integers in a String

Tags: php

I have this string the first is the hours, second minutes, third seconds.

```
744:39:46
```

How do I divide the hours '744' in PHP?

Comment: Are you asking how to parse the string?  Clearly you would need to parse out the hours before you can do any math, etc.. on it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I'm understanding you correctly, you want to get the substring `'744'` from the string `'744:39:46'`.  Since the latter string always has a particular form, you can simply use the [`explode`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.explode.php) function to split the string by commas and then take the last element:

```
$str='744:39:46';
$arr=explode(':',$str);
$string_i_want=$arr[0]; //assigns '744' to $string_i_want
```

You can also pick it out with a regular expression by using [`preg_match`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.preg-match.php):

```
$str='744:39:46';

if(preg_match('/^(\d+):\d+:\d+$/',$str,$matches))
{
  $string_i_want=$matches[1]; //assigns '744' to $string_i_want
}
else
{
  //The string didn't match...my guess is that something very weird is going on.
}
```

In the regular expression, `\d+` denotes "one or more digits", `^` denotes the beginning of the string, and `$` denotes the end of the string.  The parentheses around the first `\d+` allows for capturing of the first set of digits into `$matches[1]` (and `$matches[0]` is the entire string--ie `$matches[0]===$str`).

Answer (score 2):

```
$time = "744:39:46";
$timeunits = explode(":", $time);
$hours = $timeunits[0];
print $hours;
```

Answer (score 2):

Assuming you mean divide it into days,

```
$hours = 744;

$days = floor($hours / 24);
$hours = $hours % 24;
```

Answer (score 2):

```
$parts = explode(":", "744:39:46");
// Divide the hours
echo $parts[0] / $somevalue;
```